# Python while true loop not reaching "except ValueError"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure whats wrong with the code as I'm only just starting out on python but when an erroneous value is typed in it outputs with "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(Error value)'". However I would like it to output with "Invalid Character/s. Please Try Again." and then for the loop to continue back from the start, I wasn't able to figure out what I could change, so an explanation of what is required would be great as well.

```
ListOfNumbers = []
while True:
  Number = float(input("Enter a number >>"))
  if Number == 0:
    print ("End.")
    break
  try:
    ListOfNumbers.append(int(Number))
    Average = float(sum(ListOfNumbers))/len(ListOfNumbers)
  except ValueError:
    print ("Invalid Character/s. Please Try Again.")
    continue
print ("The total value is", sum(ListOfNumbers))
print ("The average value is", Average)
print ("The highest value is", max(ListOfNumbers))
print ("The lowest value is", min(ListOfNumbers))
ListOfNumbers.sort()
print ("List of numbers", ListOfNumbers)
```

Comment: `except` blocks only catch exceptions that happen in the `try`. This exception isn't happening in the `try`.

Comment: Your problem is that your attempting to convert your input to a float outside of the `try/except` block. Change `Number = float(input("Enter a number >>"))` to `Number = input("Enter a number >>")`.

Comment: @ChristianDean I have already tried that beforehand and it just keeps repeating the "Enter a number >>" line regardless of what you type in, however I put the try line before the "Number = float(input("Enter a number >>"))" line and it all worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueError` is exception is thrown by the line that takes in the input. Move the `try` block to catch the exception.

```
while True:
   try:
      Number = float(input("Enter a number >>"))
      if Number == 0:
         print ("End.")
         break
      ListOfNumbers.append(int(Number))
      Average = float(sum(ListOfNumbers))/len(ListOfNumbers)
   except ValueError:
      print ("Invalid Character/s. Please Try Again.")
      continue
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I did after user2357112's comment, but thank you